# how to get the lines added/deleted/modified in 2 text files in shell

Tags: shell

there are 2 files-one file is the plugin file installed in jenkins

```
  cat plugins.txt
    jenkinsinstance|plugin1|version1|activestate
    jenkinsinstance|plugin3|version3.chage|activestate
    jenkinsinstance|new-plugin|new-version|new-state
```

and the other one is the file that has values stored in the db

```
cat db.txt
jenkinsinstance|plugin1|version1|activestate
jenkinsinstance|plugin2|version2|activestate
jenkinsinstance|plugin3|version3|activestate
```

Now i have to compare these 2 files and come up with a solution that shows the plugin that has changed, added and removed in jenkins instance
but somehow i am stuck with the logic and cant figure out a way to proceed
i tried using `diff` and `comm` tool but they do not give proper results

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines plugins.txt db.txt
jenkinsinstance|plugin3|version3.chage|activestate          |  jenkinsinstance|plugin2|version2|activestate
 jenkinsinstance|new-plugin|new-version|new-state              |  jenkinsinstance|plugin3|version3|activestate
```

also

```
 diff -u plugins.txt db.txt
--- plugins.txt 2018-01-09 22:35:50.965578496 -0600
+++ db.txt      2018-01-09 01:33:28.728664084 -0600
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 jenkinsinstance|plugin1|version1|activestate
-jenkinsinstance|plugin3|version3.chage|activestate
-jenkinsinstance|new-plugin|new-version|new-state
+jenkinsinstance|plugin2|version2|activestate
+jenkinsinstance|plugin3|version3|activestate
```

these nowhere give accurate data about the lines added/deleted/modified
can someone please help me out here

Comment: How is this different from your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180482/compare-2-text-files-in-linux)?

Comment: the last question did not quite explain the exact scenario and caused confusion